# How to exclude folder from Get-Item where I don't have permissions?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a folder called `template` in which I want to exculde from `Get-ChildItem` because I do not have permissions to access that folder.  I tried:

```
$folders = Get-ChildItem -PATH $filepath -Directory -Recurse | Where-Object {!($_.Name.Equals("template"))}
```

but this still looks like it tries to access the folder before filtering it out

I also tried:

```
$folders = Get-ChildItem $filePath -Directory -Recurse | ? {$_.Name -notmatch "template"}
```

but I got the same access denied

Comment: Do you get the same result if you try:
`$folders = Get-ChildItem -PATH $filepath -Directory -Recurse | Where-Object {!($_.Name -eq "template")}`/

Comment: @trebleCode - same error

Comment: Have you tried the -Exclude parameter?

Comment: @EBGreen yep was just about to say that

Comment: https://powershell.org/forums/topic/exclude-sub-folders-from-get-childitem/

Comment: I tried `$folders = Get-ChildItem $filePath -Directory -Recurse -Exclude "temp"` and got access denied

Comment: Not sure if I am using -Exclude correctly here, but the way I am in the previous comment, I still get Access Denied

Comment: I tested -Exclude on folders I have access to and it does in fact exclude them, but for folders where I don't have access, it still throws access denied

Comment: Another old post on here suggested trying
 
-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ? {$_.permission -match 'read'}

 but also mentions it fails on PSv5. Could you try forcing an earlier version in your script?

Ex. `powershell -version 4 .\yourscriptname.ps1`?

Comment: I am using PSv3... Where did you get $_.Permission from?

Comment: @trebleCode - Ok, for some reason this doesn't throw an error now `$folders = Get-ChildItem $filePath -Directory -Exclude "temp"` but when it is done, the $folder.Count = 0

Comment: Just realized it is with the -Recurse flag when it throws the error.  Files inside `temp` have access denied

Comment: If you just don't like seeing the error, then add `-ErrorAction Ignore` (or `-ea 0` for short) to your `Get-ChildItem` command. That'll get all of the folders that it can, and ignore the ones it can't access.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician - I am trying it now.  I tried `-ea 4` but that caused `$folders.Count = 0`